# Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication) - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I don't have any idea what's wrong with this code.
I use react navigation, and it was working perfectly, but I got an error out of nowhere.
I think something is wrong with the nav

Here is [Github Repo](https://github.com/elencho/never-have-i-ever)

So this is Home.js

```
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
return (
<>
<ImageBackground source={require('../images/wall.jpeg')} style={styles.back}>
<View style={styles.box}>

<Image source={require('../images/logo.png')} style={styles.logo}/>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Questions')}>
<View style={styles.container}
 >
<Image source={require('../images/game.png')} style={styles.icons}/>
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'bpg_extrasquare_mtavruli_2009', fontSize: 20}}>გასართობი</Text>
</View>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Questions')}>
<View style={styles.container2}>
 <Text style={{fontFamily: 'bpg_extrasquare_mtavruli_2009', fontSize: 20}}>ცენზურა</Text>
<Image source={require('../images/hand.png')} style={styles.icons}/>
</View>
</TouchableOpacity>
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Questions')}>
<View style={styles.container3}>
 <Image source={require('../images/gender.png')} style={styles.icons}/>
 <Text style={{fontFamily: 'bpg_extrasquare_mtavruli_2009', fontSize: 20}}></Text>
 </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
  </View> 
 </ImageBackground> 
  </>
  );
};




 const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  function MyStack() {
  return (
   <Stack.Navigator  
    >

  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Questions" component={Questions} />
  
 </Stack.Navigator>
   );
}
```

So if you have any idea what's wrong please help

Comment: sometimes this happens to me :what worked for me --- was clean build folder clean cache of nodejs and rebuild -- i recommend to do this if it doesn't not working look in your code for mistakes

Comment: this happend to me alot of times - mostly the method i wrote up work / sometimes there can be an mistake in name when you are importing some classes/or fuctions

Comment: this happens very frequently, so there should be something wrong with navigation i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear cache and kill allnode, or there is something wrong with the code